# Create components for spacy pipeline

Tags: python, spacy

I'm currently working with Spacy and I'm exploring how I can use pipelines to work more efficiently. I'm trying to create my own components to add to a pipeline, but I keep running into some issued every time. Example :

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.blank("fr")

def lemmatizer(doc) :
    return " ".join([elt.lemma_ for elt in nlp(doc.text)])

nlp.add_pipe(lemmatizer) # add the lemmatizer to the pipeline

nlp("Hi, I'm new here.")
```

I get the following error :

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 nlp("Hi, I'm new here.")

/var/opt/data/dataiku/datadir/code-envs/python/recla_text_sci/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/language.py in __call__(self, text, disable, component_cfg)
    443             if not hasattr(proc, "__call__"):
    444                 raise ValueError(Errors.E003.format(component=type(proc), name=name))
--> 445             doc = proc(doc, **component_cfg.get(name, {}))
    446             if doc is None:
    447                 raise ValueError(Errors.E005.format(name=name))

 in lemmatizer(doc)
      1 def lemmatizer(doc) :
----> 2     return " ".join([elt.lemma_ for elt in nlp(doc.text)])

... last 2 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

/var/opt/data/dataiku/datadir/code-envs/python/recla_text_sci/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/language.py in __call__(self, text, disable, component_cfg)
    443             if not hasattr(proc, "__call__"):
    444                 raise ValueError(Errors.E003.format(component=type(proc), name=name))
--> 445             doc = proc(doc, **component_cfg.get(name, {}))
    446             if doc is None:
    447                 raise ValueError(Errors.E005.format(name=name))

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're writing a simple stateless component in spaCy. A stateless component can be defined as a function that takes a Doc and returns the same Doc. Your code has several problems.

First, about how pipelines work. You can think of a spaCy pipeline (the `nlp()` call) as working like this:

```
def do_nlp(text):
    doc = tokenizer(text) # the tokenizer is special and comes before the pipeline
    for pipe in pipes:
        doc = pipe(doc)
```

So basically each pipe is like a function, and they are called in order on the Doc.

So, with your code, the cause of the error you're getting is that inside the loop above you're calling `nlp()` again. Which calls `nlp()` again. And so on. You can't call `nlp()` inside a component and shouldn't need to.

If that were the only problem you could do this:

```
return " ".join([elt.lemma_ for elt in doc])
```

But that won't work either - you're returning a string, but you need to return a Doc.

It looks like you're trying to change each token in a Doc into its lemma. But you can't change the text of a Doc, that's a design decision in spaCy, so that won't work.

You should probably take a look at the [docs on custom components](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components).

If my understanding of what you're trying to do is correct, this doesn't seem to make sense as a pipeline component, and can just be post-processing.

Comment: After reading the link you provided, I realize I was going about this in a wrong way. Thanks for you help